# How to customize open-door login page in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

So I made a application in Oracle APEX 23.1.0, and I have set the authentication scheme type as open door. Everything works but I cant find how I can edit/customize the open door login page content. [This is the open-door login page that I want to customize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kotrv.png)

I have tried to look in the app pages area but the login page there has the original login content(username/password scheme type). Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the authentication scheme that defines your open door.

Modify the field Login Processing->Help text, for instance

```
<script>
$('.a-Wizard-title').text('Log in to my super awesome application.');
</script>
```

[image: login processing help text]

The resulting page will render that as HTML, and hence execute whatever might be there
[image: resulting login page]
You just need to use the inspect element tool to help determine what classes can be used to identify relevant page elements.

You'll be limited to 4000 characters, but there may be ways to get around that.